see the ssh command on target machine that I used to ssh into that machine
After ssh'ing from my local PC to another PC say machine B is there a linux command I can invoke on machine B where I can see the exact ssh command I used to log into it?
Example
I'm on my PC but then I ssh into machine B which has glassfish.  Part of the ssh command creates a tunnel so I can access the glassfish web console on my pc's web browser.  This is the command I use:
ssh testuser@machineb.com -L 5000:machineb.com:4848
From there I can go to my pc's web browser and type localhost:5000 to get to the glassfish admin console.
There are times though that I log ssh using the command above and then I'll monitor the servers logs on the linux terminal and forget whats the port I used to tunnel, in the case above it would be port 5000.
Is there a linux command that I can use on machine B where I can see the ssh command that I used to connect to it?
With the purpose of this to simply see the tunneled port to my local pc so I can access the glassfish web browser.
Currently I just exit out of machine B and see my last command with the port to re-login but I was wondering if there's the way I mentioned without doing that.

No, the shell command info is not passed to the remote device. If you just want to see the open tunnel ports, then you can run sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<sshd\>' on machine B, like in the answer here:  https://superuser.com/a/248391/673426
